# Can you import arrays for a specific set of locations from MK Map View?

Tags: ios, swift

My apologies if it's a dumb question as I am new to coding and learning swift as I go, but I was wondering if anyone knew if there is a way to display specific locations with Mk Map View without having to manually add an array with lat, long, title, etc.

Sorry if all that is vague, what I want to do is have a user open the app and see locations of parks near them. I have the map displayed and user location shown, but I want to pretty much run a MKLocalsearch for parks automatically without having the user have to search it themselves. Below in the code I used populateNearbyPlaces as the function to try and run the search and called it in checkLocationAuthorization function. The map is center on user location but doesn't show the places. If anyone could help it would be super appreciated

```
func checkLocationAuthorization() {
    switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        centerViewOnUserLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        populateNearbyPlaces()

        break
    case .denied:
        break
    case .notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    case .restricted:
        break
    case .authorizedAlways:
        break
    }
}

func populateNearbyPlaces() {
    var region = MKCoordinateRegion()

    region.center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
    searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "parks"
    searchRequest.region = region

    let activeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
    activeSearch.start { (response, error) in
        if response == nil {
            print("ERROR")

        } else {
            let latitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.latitude
            let longitude = response?.boundingRegion.center.longitude
            let annontation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annontation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annontation)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have a service for automatically get nearby parks and get their locations and show them on the map, you can't get them automatically

you will have to do something like this but adding your array for all parks in **.coordinate**

```
 let pasajero : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitud2blepasajero, longitud2blepasajero)  

                            let objectAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()  
                            objectAnnotation.coordinate = pasajero  
                            objectAnnotation.title = "Pasajero"  
                            self.map.addAnnotation(objectAnnotation)
```

plz rate if was useful